# How to change the layer colour in google earth engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am working on a Google Earth Engine app where I would like to allow the user to draw an area of interest polygon (AOI). After drawing, the AOI polygon should only show the boundary colour and no fill color so that the map under AOI polygon can be viewed. I do not know how to make the polygon with no fill color. Could you please help me with this? Below is my code:

```
var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();
drawingTools.setShown(false);
while (drawingTools.layers().length() > 0) {
  var layer = drawingTools.layers().get(0);
  drawingTools.layers().remove(layer);
}
var dummyGeometry =
    ui.Map.GeometryLayer({geometries: null, name: 'grid', color: 'green'});

drawingTools.layers().add(dummyGeometry);
function clearGeometry() {
  var layers = drawingTools.layers();
  layers.get(0).geometries().remove(layers.get(0).geometries().get(0));
}
function drawRectangle() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('rectangle');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

function drawPolygon() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('polygon');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

var symbol = {
  rectangle: '⬛',
  polygon: '',
  point: '',
};
/*
* Panel setup
*/
var controlPanel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Label('1. Select a drawing mode.'),
    ui.Button({
      label: symbol.rectangle + ' Rectangle',
      onClick: drawRectangle,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
    }),
    ui.Button({
      label: symbol.polygon + ' Polygon',
      onClick: drawPolygon,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
    }),
  ],
  layout: null,
});

var main_panel = ui.Panel({style:{position: 'top-left'}});
main_panel.add(controlPanel);
Map.add(main_panel);
```

Thank you.